# High resolution support - Android

Tags: android

I have 1280*800 as the highest resolution image in the assets folder.

Now Nexus came up with 2560*1600 double the resolution size, how could we handle it.

If I ignore updating the application in the market, will I loose rating in the perspective of look at higher resolution devices?

Comment: how are you so sure that the limit is 1280x800?

Comment: Am not talking about the limit, I am just stating - I have my application with the resolution of 1280*800 , now do I need to release an update with the 2560*1600?

Comment: you should! it depends on your future targets.

Comment: Just to know, If I have no updates in the functional way - do I need to? As it is going to increase my apk size , and moreover do I notice any blur effect in Nexus device if I dont update?

Comment: Oh yes sub assets are very noticeable on high res devices, especially the Nexus 10.

Comment: Already my apk size is 25MB, could you give an idea to stand this? Could I create 2560*800 assets and remove 1280*800?

Answer (score 3):

u can add new resolution picture in the res/drawable-xhdpi folder for nexus

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: This is a generic statement

Comment: Yes, because Android provides a generic solution to handle resolutions, with the density buckets. You should use it.

Comment: apply water to burned area, @Sreeram xD